# Ansible and AWS Subnets

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I am relatively new to working with Ansible Core / Tower and I am at a complete loss what is causing the following issues. I have spent the past two days reading everything I could find on the topic and I am still stuck, looking for help.

Here is what I currently have setup (among other Ansible playbooks, roles, and tasks to create brand new VPC).

Below are the tasks that I am using to create a set of new subnets, one per availability zone, and get the results back from what is created. These tasks all works perfectly as verified through the AWS Console.

```
### Create the Internet-facing DMZ subnets ###
- name: Create Subnet(s) in VPC - DMZ
  ec2_vpc_subnet:
    state: present
    vpc_id: "{{ new_vpc_info['vpcs'][0]['id'] }}"
    region: "{{ vpc_region }}"
    az: "{{ item.az }}"
    cidr: "{{ item.subnet }}"
    resource_tags:
       Name: "{{ item.name }}"
       Role: "{{ role_tag }}"
       Team: "{{ team_tag }}"
       Product Area: "{{ product_area_tag }}"
       Portfolio: "{{ portfolio_tag }}"
  with_items: "{{ dmz_subnet_az }}"

- name: Get Sunbet Info - DMZ
  ec2_vpc_subnet_facts:
    region: "{{ vpc_region }}"
    filters:
      "tag:Name": "{{ item.name }}"
  with_items: "{{ dmz_subnet_az }}"
  register: new_dmz_subnets

- debug:
    var=new_dmz_subnets
```

The output of the "debug" command is provided below, truncated to remove the rest of the subnets and redacted so I do not get yelled at, which matches up to what is in the AWS Console.

```
{
    "changed": false,
    "_ansible_verbose_always": true,
    "new_dmz_subnets": {
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "changed": false,
        "results": [
            {
                "_ansible_parsed": true,
                "subnets": [
                    {
                        "tags": {
                            "Product Area": "Engineering Tools",
                            "Portfolio": "Shared Platform and Operations",
                            "Role": "splunk-proof-of-concept",
                            "Name": "DMZ_Subnet_A",
                            "Team": "Engineering Tools"
                        },
                        "subnet_id": "subnet-XXXX",
                        "assign_ipv6_address_on_creation": false,
                        "default_for_az": false,
                        "state": "available",
                        "ipv6_cidr_block_association_set": [],
                        "availability_zone": "us-east-1a",
                        "vpc_id": "vpc-XXXX",
                        "cidr_block": "x.x.x.x/24",
                        "available_ip_address_count": 251,
                        "id": "subnet-XXXX",
                        "map_public_ip_on_launch": false
                    }
                ],
                "changed": false,
                "_ansible_item_label": {
                    "subnet": "x.x.x.x/24",
                    "az": "us-east-1a",
                    "name": "DMZ_Subnet_A"
                },
                "item": {
                    "subnet": "x.x.x.x/24",
                    "az": "us-east-1a",
                    "name": "DMZ_Subnet_A"
                },
                "_ansible_item_result": true,
                "failed": false,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "profile": null,
                        "aws_secret_key": null,
                        "aws_access_key": null,
                        "security_token": null,
                        "region": "us-east-1",
                        "filters": {
                            "tag:Name": "DMZ_Subnet_A"
                        },
                        "ec2_url": null,
                        "subnet_ids": [],
                        "validate_certs": true
                    }
                },
                "_ansible_ignore_errors": null,
                "_ansible_no_log": false
            },
            {
                "_ansible_parsed": true,
                "subnets": [
                    {
                        "tags": {
                            "Product Area": "Engineering Tools",
                            "Portfolio": "Shared Platform and Operations",
                            "Role": "splunk-proof-of-concept",
                            "Name": "DMZ_Subnet_B",
                            "Team": "Engineering Tools"
                        },
                        "subnet_id": "subnet-XXXX",
                        "assign_ipv6_address_on_creation": false,
                        "default_for_az": false,
                        "state": "available",
                        "ipv6_cidr_block_association_set": [],
                        "availability_zone": "us-east-1b",
                        "vpc_id": "vpc-XXXX",
                        "cidr_block": "x.x.x.x/24",
                        "available_ip_address_count": 251,
                        "id": "subnet-XXXX",
                        "map_public_ip_on_launch": false
                    }
                ],
                "changed": false,
                "_ansible_item_label": {
                    "subnet": "x.x.x.x/24",
                    "az": "us-east-1b",
                    "name": "DMZ_Subnet_B"
                },
                "item": {
                    "subnet": "x.x.x.x/24",
                    "az": "us-east-1b",
                    "name": "DMZ_Subnet_B"
                },
                "_ansible_item_result": true,
                "failed": false,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "profile": null,
                        "aws_secret_key": null,
                        "aws_access_key": null,
                        "security_token": null,
                        "region": "us-east-1",
                        "filters": {
                            "tag:Name": "DMZ_Subnet_B"
                        },
                        "ec2_url": null,
                        "subnet_ids": [],
                        "validate_certs": true
                    }
                },
                "_ansible_ignore_errors": null,
                "_ansible_no_log": false
            },

......

            }
        ]
    },
    "_ansible_no_log": false
}
```

Now onto the tasks that I am having issues getting working, below is my most recent attempt, which may be completely in left field due to me trying everything I found to get it working.  I am attempting to get a list of the "subnet_id" from the registered "new_dmz_subnets" variable, then concatenating it with a "name" that is set in a vars file, and finally using that information to create a NAT Gateway within each of the subnets.

```
### Create the NAT Gateway in VPC ###
- name: Set DMZ Subnet facts
  set_fact:
    subnet_id_items:
      subnet_id: '{{ item.subnets | map(attribute="subnet_id") | list }}'
  with_items: "{{ new_dmz_subnets }}"
  register: subnet_id_list

- name: Set Name and DMZ Subnet loop facts
  set_fact:
    name_subnet_items:
      name: "{{ nat_gateway.name }}"
      subnet_id: "{{ item.subnet_id }}"
  loop: "{{ subnet_id_list }}"
  register: name_subnet_list

- debug:
    var=name_subnet_list

- name: Create NAT Gateway, allocate new EIP, in VPC
  ec2_vpc_nat_gateway:
    state: present
    subnet_id: "{{ item.subnet_id }}"
    region: "{{ vpc_region }}"
    wait: yes
    if_exist_do_not_create: true
    tags:
      Name: "{{ item.name }}"
      Role: "{{ role_tag }}"
      Team: "{{ team_tag }}"
      Product Area: "{{ product_area_tag }}"
      Portfolio: "{{ portfolio_tag }}"
  with_items: "{{ name_subnet_list }}"
  register: new_nat_gateway

- debug:
    var=new_nat_gateway
```

When I ran this setup, I got the following fatal error message, which is pretty much the same across every variation I have attempted.

```
12:55:15
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'subnets'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/var/lib/awx/projects/_6__erik_andresen_git/ansible/splunk_poc_playbook/roles/create_networking_role/tasks/create_gateways_task.yml': line 21, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n### Starting working on this Task ###\n- name: Set DMZ Subnet facts\n  ^ here\n"
}
```

Please let me know if I can provide any additional details and thanks in advance for the help!!!

-- Erik

Answer (score 0):

I came across a setup that actually works! It may not be the best way to do it and I am still open to suggestions, but it at least works.

Here is code of the "ec2_vpc_subnet" module and collecting the Subnet IDs for later use in the playbook.

```
### Create the Internet-facing DMZ subnets ###
- name: Create Subnet(s) in VPC - DMZ
  ec2_vpc_subnet:
    state: present
    vpc_id: "{{ vpc_id }}"
    region: "{{ vpc_region }}"
    az: "{{ item.az }}"
    cidr: "{{ item.subnet }}"
    resource_tags:
       Name: "{{ item.name }}"
       Role: "{{ role_tag }}"
       Team: "{{ team_tag }}"
       Product Area: "{{ product_area_tag }}"
       Portfolio: "{{ portfolio_tag }}"
       Created By: "{{ created_by }}"
  with_items: "{{ dmz_subnet_az }}"
  register: new_dmz_subnets

- name: Set facts for Subnet - DMZ
  set_fact:
    subnet_dmz_id: "{{ subnet_dmz_id | default({}) | combine({ item.subnet.tags.Name: item.subnet.id }) }}"
  loop: "{{ new_dmz_subnets.results }}"

- debug:
    var=subnet_dmz_id
```

And here is the use of the Subnet IDs in the "ec2_vpc_nat_gateway" module to create a NAT Gateway within each Availability Zone.

```
### Create the NAT Gateway in VPC ###
- name: Create NAT Gateway, allocate new EIP, in VPC
  ec2_vpc_nat_gateway:
    state: present
    # NAT Gateways being deployed in DMZ subnets
    subnet_id: "{{ subnet_dmz_id[item.subnet_name] }}"
    region: "{{ vpc_region }}"
    wait: yes
    if_exist_do_not_create: true
    # Tags not supported in the "ec2_vpc_nat_gateway" module
    # https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/44339
    #tags:
    #  Name: "{{ item.name }}"
    #  Role: "{{ role_tag }}"
    #  Team: "{{ team_tag }}"
    #  Product Area: "{{ product_area_tag }}"
    #  Portfolio: "{{ portfolio_tag }}"
    #  Created By: "{{ created_by }}"
  with_items: "{{ nat_gateway }}"
  register: new_nat_gateway

- debug:
    var=new_nat_gateway
```